# Difference between Main element, Content div and wrapper div?

Tags: css, html, web, element

Can anybody explain when I would use these elements specifically or are these interchangeable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What research have you done? Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I used the search button the questions asked was not the same one I asked.

Answer (score 10):

The **[`<main>` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-main-element-20121217/#the-main-element)** must occur only **once** on a page, and **cannot** be a child of an `<article>`, `<aside>`, `<footer>`, `<header>` or `<nav>` element. It's where you typically put the **[`role="main" attribute`](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#main)** if you're working with [**accessibility**](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/).

There is no pre-defined `<content>` element, though you are free to **[create your own](https://www.w3.org/TR/custom-elements/)**.

The [**`<div>` element**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-div-element) (as in `<div class="content">` and `<div class="wrapper">`) can go wherever [**flow content**](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/dom.html#flow-content-1) is expected. That means it can have (almost) any element as a parent.

The classes affixed to the above two `<div>` elements denote different styling rules. Typically, a class of `.wrapper` is used to defined the main body of a document, and control how 'offset' it should be from the edge of the page. As such, there is usually only **one** occurrence of `<div class="wrapper">` on a page. The class `.content` is used to define and separate out individual blocks of content, and as such, there are usually **multiple** `<div class="content">` blocks on a page.

Although the classes `.wrapper` and `.content` are *fairly* commonly-used (and built into a number of frameworks), you are under no obligation to make use of them.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: So basically you're saying I can use either div class="content" or Content div class="wrapper" they both are the same thing, or I can just use the main element instead of either content or wrapper am I correct or nah?

Comment: They're both essentially the same thing - `<div>` elements. The 'class' just applies different CSS styles to elements that share the same class. For example `.content { color: red; }` would make **all** of the `<div class="content"` elements have red text. The same would go for `.wrapper`. The class names you see in frameworks simply illustrate their intended **usage**. It **doesn't matter** what they're called; the naming just helps you remember rules that you set up. For example, `.content` is easier to remember for blocks of content rather than `.ajksdf` (which would be **equally** valid).